# Why isn't the [CLLocationManager location] updated when the CLLocationManagerDelegate message is sent?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

When the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` (or its deprecated equivalent `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`) message is sent to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, the [CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateToLocation%3afromLocation%3a) states that:

> By the time this message is delivered to your delegate, the new
>   location data is also available directly from the CLLocationManager
>   object. The newLocation parameter may contain the data that was cached
>   from a previous usage of the location service. You can use the
>   timestamp property of the location object to determine how recent the
>   location data is.

However, in practice, `CLLocationManager`'s `location` property is not updated.  Why not?

I have created a sample project to demonstrate this: 
https://github.com/sibljon/CoreLocationDidUpdateToLocationBug

The relevant code is in `JSViewController`, a snippet of which is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10000.0; // 10 km
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.purpose = @"To show you nearby hotels.";
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appDidEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"New location: %@", newLocation);
    NSLog(@"Old location: %@", oldLocation);
    NSLog(@"- [CLLocationManager location]: %@", manager.location);
}

//- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
//{
//    for (CLLocation *location in locations)
//    {
//        NSLog(@"Current location: %@", locations);
//    }
//    NSLog(@"- [CLLocationManager location]: %@", manager.location);
//}

#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)appWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)appDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, it's not updated? The first value you get may be a cached value, and then you should get a real value, assuming you're getting data. Are you testing this on a device?

Comment: You noticed that you are always printing the newLocation and never the oldLocation right? That actually doesn't do anything, only prevents you to see if the newLocation and oldLocation are different. I would suggest that: maybe didUpdateToLocation is being called but you don't have a new location just getting the previous one. This can happen and the documentation talks about that.

Comment: @all: I can reproduce the bug every time.  Here are the steps to reproduce: 
1. Download my sample project at https://github.com/sibljon/CoreLocationDidUpdateToLocationBug
2. Run in Simulator
3. Set your location to Apple (Debug->Location->Apple) and observe console
4. Set your location to Germany (Debug->Location->Custom) -- Latitude 51, Longitude 9 -- and observe console
5. Note how when you change the location to Germany:
    newLocation == <+51.00000000,+9.00000000>
    - [CLLocationManager location] == <+33.67879735,-112.62216181>

Comment: Observe the console output when switching locations from "Apple" to "Germany".  newLocation is CORRECT and [CLLocationManager location] is INCORRECT: http://cl.ly/image/2c3z1s3c3r0n

Comment: @rdelmar by "not updated", I mean that it contains the same location value as oldLocation (which is indeed the previous location).  It does not contain the value of newLocation (which is the correct location).  I am testing on the Simulator.

Comment: @jonsibley Thanks for clarifying that. I did not do the same test case but only testing on the device, so I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug and I have filed a bug report with Apple.  A mirror of the bug report can be found on Open Radar:

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2682402

Answer (score 0):

As you have read in the documentation, the locationManagerDelegate might deliver cached data to the callback method.

This actually happens quite frequently so what you need to do is check the timestamp of the `newLocation` against `oldLocation` or current time, to see if they are different enough (how different is up to you to decide based on your app's needs).

Here's a snippet of how you could do the check against the current time:

```
    if ([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] < 600) // 10 minutes
```

Comment: This is not the problem I am experiencing.  In my case newLocation is correct.  The problem is that [CLLocationManager location] is not correct, even though the documentation promises that it will be updated before the delegate is messaged.